# Can you use an oil extractor on transmission oil?

Tags: transmission, oil-change

Is this a good idea and will it work effectively?

If you put a hose through a transmission input hole wouldn’t the pipe not make it to the bottom because of gears being in the way etc or is it still likely to work effectively?

Thanks.

Comment: Effectively for what? Are you taking a sample or you want to swap your transmission oil without lifting the car? The dipstick has to read oil levels so it will get at least part of the way down into the oil reservoir.

Comment: it is better to use the drainplug,the drainplug is often magnetic and can tell you how the condition of your transmission are by trapping metall shavings.

Comment: @GdD I want to remove the transmission fluid without draining the car.  Unlike engineboil changes doesn’t seem many people do this because it’s not viable or a good idea?  If so why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be done, to a certain extent. A tube may not go all the way to the bottom of the pan, but as the dipstick has to get a good way into the reservoir you will be able to get some of the fluid. However, it's not a good idea because:

- You will only get some of the fluid. A tube is unlikely to get all the way to the bottom of the pan, so you'll only get a fraction. Dropping the pan and letting it drain out will get much more fluid out
- The tube could get stuck in a gear, it's unlikely but it would be bad
- If the fluid needs changing so does the filter, and the filter is very important in the health of the transmission
- A fluid/filter change lets you check for metal, which is important. Metal filings or shreds is a sign there's a problem, and it's cheaper to deal with these things while they are small problems